# How do I sort the result of this MySQL query as I want them?

Tags: mysql, sorting

Here's the data I have;

```
type      valid blocked
--------- ----- --------
CPI       0     0
CPI       1     0
CPI       0     1
CPI       1     1
CPA       0     0
CPA       1     0
CPA       0     1
CPA       1     1
CPE       0     0
CPE       1     0
CPE       0     1
CPE       1     1
PIN       0     0
PIN       1     0
PIN       0     1
PIN       1     1
```

Here's how I want it sorted;

```
type      valid blocked
--------- ----- --------
CPI       1     0
CPA       1     0
CPI       1     1
CPA       1     1
CPI       0     0
CPA       0     0
CPI       0     1
CPA       0     1
CPE       1     0
CPE       1     1
CPE       0     0
CPE       0     1
PIN       1     0
PIN       1     1
PIN       0     0
PIN       0     1
```

So, CPI and CPA first, sorted by valid then unblocked.  Next its CPI sorted by valid then unblocked and finally PIN, again sorted by valid and unblocked.

Is that even possible to sort like this in one query?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
order by case when type in ('CPI','CPA') then 1
              when type = 'CPE' then 2
              when type = 'PIN' then 3
         end,
         valid <> 0, 
         blocked
```

Comment: Great, you are missing a comma after end and valid <> 0 had to be changed to valid = 0 (strangely?) but otherwise works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table
order by `type` in ('CPI','CPA') desc
    , `type` = 'CPE' desc
    , `type` = 'PIN' desc
    , valid desc, blocked
    , `type` = 'CPI' desc
;
```

Comment: If I might make a suggestion, some description of what your code does might help the questioner.